# Cannot insert ajax data into database codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I want to insert some ajax post data into database. But when I'm clicking submit, no data is being inserted.
view(header.php)

```
     $(function(){
 $(".submit").click(function(){
transaction_student_id=$(".student_id").val();
transaction_particular_name=$(".particular_name").val();
transaction_id=$(".transaction_id").val();
 jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url().'user/add_transaction'; ?>",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {transaction_student_id: transaction_student_id,transaction_particular_name:transaction_particular_name,transaction_id:transaction_id},
                    success: function(data) {

                    }
                    }); 
 });
  });
```

Controller (User.php)

```
public function add_transaction()
      {
        $columns_and_fields = array('transaction_id','transaction_particular_name','transaction_student_id');
       foreach ($columns_and_fields as $key) 
      $data[$key]=$this->input->post($key);
        $query=$this->Mdl_data->insert_transaction($data);
        if($query)
          redirect('User','refresh');
      }
```

Model (Mdl_data.php)

```
public function insert_transaction($data=array())
    {

        $tablename='transaction';
        $query=$this->db->insert($tablename,$data);
        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: This error is shown up in controller directory.     failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\southern\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 268

Answer (score 0):

First of all, declare the variable in JavaScript with keyword `var`

```
var transaction_student_id=$(".student_id").val();
```

Before starting the `Ajax` use `console.log()` to know if the variables have data or not

The second thing is you are not getting the data with right way in the controller

Try like this

```
public function add_transaction()
{
   $columns_and_fields = array('transaction_id' = $this->input->post('transaction_id'), 
      'transaction_particular_name' => $this->input->post('transaction_particular_name'), 
      'transaction_student_id' => $this->input->post('transaction_student_id')); 

   $query=$this->Mdl_data->insert_transaction($columns_and_fields);
     if($query){
        redirect('User','refresh');

     }
}
```

Don't use the extra line of code without any reason

```
public function insert_transaction($data = array())
{
   return $this->db->insert('transaction', $data);
}
```

Comment: Its working when I put the form action="add_transaction" instead of action="<?php echo base_url().'user/add_transaction'; ?>"

Comment: it means you are not defining the route correctly. Define route in `application/config/route.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your code first.

Do you get all the data in controller? Try to dump POST values `var_dump($_POST)` in controller if ajax is successfully sending the data.

From there, you can see if the data in successfully sent from the front end.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/add_transaction",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        transaction_student_id: transaction_student_id,
        transaction_particular_name: transaction_particular_name,
        transaction_id: transaction_id
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    },
    error: function( xhr, status ) {
        /** Open developer tools and go to the Console tab */
        console.log( xhr );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change it

```
     $(function(){
 $(".submit").click(function(){
transaction_student_id=$(".student_id").val();
transaction_particular_name=$(".particular_name").val();
transaction_id=$(".transaction_id").val();
 jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url().'user/add_transaction'; ?>",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {transaction_student_id: transaction_student_id,transaction_particular_name:transaction_particular_name,transaction_id:transaction_id},
                    success: function(data) {
alert(data + ' id added' );
window.location.reload(); // force to reload page
                    }
                    }); 
 });
  });
```

at controller

```
public function add_transaction()
      { // use it only for ajax call or create another one 
        $columns_and_fields = array();
// 'transaction_id','transaction_particular_name','transaction_student_id'
       foreach ($_POST as $key) 
{
array_push($columns_and_fields , array(
 'transaction_student_id' => $key['transaction_student_id'],
'transaction_particular_name'=>$key['transaction_particular_name'],
'transaction_id'=>$key['transaction_id']
  )
);
}
        $this->Mdl_data->insert_transaction_array($columns_and_fields);

      }
```

and at model create new method

```
public function insert_transaction_array($data=array())
    {

        $tablename='transaction';
        $this->db->insert_batch($tablename,$data);

    }
```